# How do you get a Mr Handy?

Tags: fallout-shelter

The new Fallout Shelter update comes with a new feature, the Mr Handy robot. How do you acquire them, and do they count as population?

Comment: +1 because this question prompted me to check if Bethesda had finally released the Android version. They just did.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Mr. Handy is mainly a convenience item to automate some manual tasks (like harvesting rooms), and can be bought in the item shop for 0.99$. There is also a small chance to get him from lunchboxes.

Comment: There's speculation that he can also be found when exploring the wasteland.

Comment: Very very low chance of getting him in a lunchbox.

Answer (score 15):

Got him on android from the lunchbox

[image]

Answer (score 6):

So far there are two ways of getting one:

- Buy one or a pack of five in the store
- Get one through a lunchbox

Not sure yet if they can be acquired otherwise. Rumours say that they might also be acquired in the wasteland, but that is yet to be confirmed.

Answer (score 2):

**You can earn him from Mr. Handy Boxes**, which are earned from Quests, Objectives, or buying them with real money, *or you have a very, very, very, very small chance of earning them in a Lunchbox.*

Answer (score 0):

They can be bought in the store gotten from lunchboxes gotten from finishing objectives, and as MrJre said possibly in the wasteland.

Comment: This answer does not add anything that is not already covered by other answers.

Comment: @GodEmperorDune, actually it does. None have mentioned that Mr. Handy can be obtained as a reward for finishing some objective. That's how I got it.